# Common Lisp define replace function

Tags: replace, common-lisp

I have following task:

Define a function **replace-element** that searches a given list for a given element x and replaces each element x with a given element y.

I am a super beginner and have no idea how to do this.

Maybe there is someone who can help me. Thanks a lot!!

For example:

(replace-element ‘a ‘b ‘(a b c a b c))

(B B C B B C)

Comment: You can write a function `copy-list` that copies a list `xs` by returning `'()` when `xs` is the empty list, and otherwise returns the result of consing the first element of `xs` onto `(copy-list (cdr xs))`. Similarly you can write `replace-element` by doing the same thing, but checking the first element of the list against `x` and consing either the first element of `xs` or `y` onto `(replace-element (cdr xs))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing this which, again, you probably cannot submit as homework, but it shows you an approach.

First of all, `tconc` and friends to accumulate lists:

```
(defun empty-tconc ()
  ;; make an empty accumulator for TCONC
  (cons nil nil))

(defun tconc (v into)
  ;; destructively add V to the end of the accumulator INTO, return
  ;; INTO
  (if (null (car into))
      (setf (car into) (list v)
            (cdr into) (car into))
    (setf (cdr (cdr into)) (list v)
          (cdr into) (cdr (cdr into))))
  into)

(defun tconc-value (into)
  ;; Retrieve the value of an accumulator
  (car into))
```

Next the answer:

```
(defun replace-element (x y l)
  (replace-element-loop x y l (empty-tconc)))

(defun replace-element-loop (x y l accumulator)
  (if (null l)
      (tconc-value accumulator)
    (replace-element-loop
     x y (rest l)
     (tconc (if (eql (first l) x) y (first l)) accumulator))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you do the tail call recursion in one function using optional arguments or key arguments:

```
(defun replace-element (element replacer l &key (acc '()) (test #'eql))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        ((funcall test (car l) element) (replace-element element replacer (cdr l) :acc (cons replacer acc) :test test))
        (t (replace-element element replacer (cdr l) :acc (cons (car l) acc) :test test))))
```

It is also possible to use reduce for this:

```
(defun replace-element (element replacer l &key (test #'eql))
  (nreverse 
    (reduce (lambda (res el)
              (if (funcall test el element)
                (cons replacer res)
                (cons el res)))
            l
            :initial-value '())))
```